# Data filtration React Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I want to filter my data for highcharts. What exactly I am trying to achieve is to apply `Highstock rangeSelector` functionality for all other highcharts modules like word cloud, pie chart etc. As soon as I click on `1m` option of highstock, it filters through the data within `one month` range of other charts too.

I could not find a work around for the one, so I thought of another way, is to define custom filter buttons like `1m, 1d and 1y` and fetch the data for charts on the Click event of those buttons.

Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zvtkjo

I am fetching the data using a function in button.js file and passing the data as props to two charts: highstock and wordcloud, so that onClick of that button, the data gets passed to those charts. But the charts are rendering empty.

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: Hi @bubble-cord, Please refer this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-emixpp?file=button.js - your project structure seems to work fine, but the problem is caused by the data source.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for resolving. But when I am using the similar code in my browser, the data from API consoles/postman properly. But it does not render the chart even after that. What should be done for that because I want to fetch data on Click only, since API is fetching the data properly.

Comment: Please provide me with an example of your data structure.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have already included my data API in my code link.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `data1: data1` insted of `data1: this.data1`. Additionally, you do not need to use `JSON.parse` method. Please refer to the code below:

```
class Button extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data1: [],
            data2: []
        }
    }

    getData = async () => {
        var res = await axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ybp8o');
        var data1 = res.data;
        data1 = data1.map(key => [key[0]*1000, key[1]]); 


        var res2 = await axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/f499k');
        var data2 = res2.data;

        this.setState({
            data1: data1,
            data2: data2
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="year" onClick={this.getData}>1 year</button>
                <Timeline ye={this.state.data1} />
                <Word ne={this.state.data2} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6wxjn1?file=button.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. So can I develop in similar manner more buttons with different data. Like Month button and then calling data in each just like Year button?

Comment: Can you look at this and suggest the conditional rendering of multiple charts based on props they are receiving. I mean, If 'Year' button is clicked, it should render charts with year props or if 'month' button is clicked, it should render charts with month props respectively. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nslbjw)

Comment: @bubble-cord, Sure, please check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6wxjn1?file=button.js

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Big appreciation to you. You are a savior :) Last If you could tell little bit the line where you binded the onClick function twice even after using arrow function?

Comment: @bubble-cord, I am glad I could help. I have binded only the external function to be able to pass an argument in `getData` method. Maybe there is a better way to do it ;)

Comment: Got it. Thanks :) :)